# React double pipe in an onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen some React code where double pipe is used in an onClick:

```
<button onClick={() => setOne(false) || setTwo(false)}>Click</button>
```

What does the double pipe do in this structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: I dont think so as setState does not return a boolean

Comment: It's still the same operator, though. This isn't any special React/JSX syntax, just basic JS.

Comment: its same as doing ```() =>  { if (!setOne(false)) setTwo(false) }```

Comment: All values in JS can be seen as booleans, not just `true` / `false`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: If `setOne` is a state setter returned from `useState`, this usage of `||` doesn't make sense to me. State setters return void. If it is another function, it may return a boolean, hence working in the way @jonrsharpe mentioned

Comment: They don't return void, that's not a value; they return undefined, which is false-y. This is basically a hacky way to call two functions, you could also use the comma operator or add braces to define an actual block body.

Comment: Didn't know they return undefined, thanks.